# Highchart - ThingSpeak - IoT - issues with graphs (axes)

Tags: graph, highcharts, iot, multiple-axes

I use Highcharts for my ThingSpeak IoT project.

All is fine except these things, which just makes me angry (I cannot find a solution on my own... I have been trying with my frind Google for last 3 days without any success).

Here is my project page: http://net.cekuj.net/

**There are my issues:**
1) I cannot see the most top number next to the Y axes (I can see only the tick, not the number - if you check browser console, it is there but it has wrong X and Y coordinates)
2) I cannot align "tick mark" for all Y axes according to the manual - I would like to align them "on" mark, but now there are still "between"... and yes I use added a var for this :(
3) I would like to use decimalplace setting independently for every series of data - for example - Temperature will have 1 decimal place, humidex will have 0 decimal place etc. is that possible?
4) I added major ticks, but no succes with adding minor ticks :(

I would be really happy if any of these 4 issues would be solved, thank you for your help and time!

EDIT:
Also autorefresh is not working, but it seems to be because of wrong URL pattern, will be fixed later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to set the **yAxis.showLastLabel** options to true

   Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hqv97ws0/

   ```
   yAxis: {
       showLastLabel: true,
   },
   ```

   API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.showLastLabel

---

3. You can set how many decimal values should be shown in the tooltip for each series:

   API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.tooltip.valueDecimals

---

2. I don't understand here - could you reproduce this issue as a really simple chart with sample data? You can use the above demo.

---

4. That's weird, ticks should be applied with setting the **yAxis.minorTicks** to true. Could you reproduce this issue also?

   Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dLy6x59q/

Comment: Hi, first of all I wanna thank you fro your reply! I have fixed the issue number #1 and #4. Only two remains: #2 - check my graph, I will add a jsfiddle code ASAP. #3 - please, could you edit my jsfiddle and show me how? Because I have tried to add valueDecimals to yaxis wothout any success.

Comment: Here is the link for jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Eldenroot/qbes63fr/1/

Comment: #2 Please notice that `tickmarkPlacement` feature applies only to the category type and it is implemented only in Highcharts - not Highstock. https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis however, I think that you can achieve a wanted result by changing the `yAxis.labels.y` value, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s0t4r9gp/

Comment: #3 your series are rendered dynamically and proposal solutions from my site are: 1. after 430 line add a condition to check which series should have a different `valueDecimals` 2.  do an series.update in the chart.events.load callback, when the series will be already applied, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hsLj78xc/

Comment: #2 - OK, but my data are dynamic,  does it have any side-effect? And for #3 - need to check, because I can set global valueDecimals to all series right now, with your proposal it should be working, good idea, I hope that I will handle it :) I will let you know later today when I get back to home.

Comment: #2 there shouldn't be any side-effect - this option just sets the label positions.

Comment: OK, great! Thank you! Can I ask you with a last not issue but an advice? I would like to implement date picker into my existing code but I am not a JS guy - this is a tutorial, but I have hard times to implement it - not working at all.

Comment: OK, here is my latest working code: https://jsfiddle.net/Eldenroot/qbes63fr/6/ I would like to add last thing - date picker selector - accroding to this tutorial - https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38934 I am not sure where to put it into the CODE (I am not a JS guy, giving me a blank page with no data). Thank you! BTW - is possible to use this more efficient method for hide/show all series? http://jsfiddle.net/pGuEv/

Comment: Here is a demo with implemented `dataPicker` in the `chart.events.load callback` : https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3qtvmgk6/ The method for hide/show I think that the approach which you have shared is a really good one

Comment: Thank you very much! All is solved and working! Here is my site: http://net.cekuj.net/

Comment: Thank you! Without you it would not be even possible!

Comment: Just my last question about tooltips dateformat - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13219 what do you think? I use my custom date formats for tooltips, it works fine but it is ignored where you group the data.

Comment: Could you ask this question as a separate topic? This one is overflowed I think. And please simplified the demo as much as you can to show the issue.